# Debian Bookworm RC1 iso installer won't start on Virtualbox 7.0.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.2, how to find the status of this issue?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, virtualbox, debian-installer, bugs

The installer won't start in graphical mode or text mode.

Where to go to review/discuss/report possible bugs in the iso and/or installer?

https://cdimage.debian.org/images/bookworm_di_rc1/amd64/iso-cd/ does not seem to say, nor does www debian org CD faq nor lists debian org debian-testing

I have tried the three different graphics emulations in Virtualbox. I wish to test UEFI installs. Secure boot is disabled, and disabling I/O APIC gives a configuration error. PAE/NX and Nested VT-x/AMD-V are on, but it should be recorded in a bug that these will not work if so. The VM has 4G of RAM and 4 cores allocated to it.

https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/DebianCd has a link to IRC, but I don't have a safe set-up for that, and am not comfortable with the security arrangements for it used naively.

There are no bugs about the installer on https://bugs.debian.org/release-critical/debian/all.html
Searching https://udd.debian.org/bugs/ for "bookworm" (radio button) and "installer bugs" (tickbox) found nothing.

The same output occurs with and without the vga=788 option as far as I can see:

[image: The installer errors for the Graphical Install (default settings)]

[image: The installer errors for the Graphical Install (without vga=788)]

Edit: The text installer shows part of a stack trace on pressing alt+f5, I got the rest on alt+f3 with `dmesg | less`
[image: start of stack trace]

[image: text installer stack trace]

Comment: What errors does text mode install produce? Does Bullseye install work?

Comment: No repro on VBox Version 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.2) running on Deb 11. Both graphical and text mode install went just fine.

Comment: @JaromandaX debian-11.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso with sha256 sum
e482910626b30f9a7de9b0cc142c3d4a079fbfa96110083be1d0b473671ce08d works fine.
The text mode shows a white screen with a black, steady block cursor, no errors are displayed.
However, alt+f5 shows a stack trace I've added to the main question as I can't put the screen shot here.

Comment: The ISO file I'm trying is da866b6958096e89200ba73002dd1c45bbbcde65845e129e10df6e0b03ab3884  debian-bookworm-DI-rc1-amd64-netinst.iso

Comment: @Peregrino69 I have reproduced this on two different 22.04LTS machines on version 7.0.6 r155176 (Qt5.15.3)
I will test on Debian 12 as well, but I don't have VBox on that system right now.

Comment: OK, it's not available for bookworm yet. I don't have an 11.6 install at present. I acknowledge that this could be an Ubuntu or Virtualbox packaging bug.

Comment: This bug has been raised at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1036310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The RC1 installer announcement](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2023/04/msg00000.html) includes links to [known errata](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/errata) and [the installer page](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/). In general, the recommendation is to [submit an installation report](https://d-i.debian.org/manual/en.amd64/ch05s04.html#submit-bug); you can view [current installation reports](https://bugs.debian.org/installation-reports) on the `installation-reports` pseudo-package.

The relevant mailing list for your situation is probably [`debian-cd`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-cd/).

Comment: The errata list is helpful, thanks.

The link https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=0;dist=unstable;ordering=normal;repeatmerged=0;src=installation-report is to the list of bugs for the installation-report package, not the actual reports. Do you know where I could find the reports? Or are they confidential? I will need to check whether the other links you've provided are as described or not.


The package looks useful for following up this issue, so thank you for pointing it out.

I will ask on the list if it is the right place to ask about this as it seems low traffic.

Comment: Apologies, I missed out the final s in “installation-reports” — I’ve updated the link in the answer.